# Speed up honeycomb display in a Manipulate expression

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate, geometry

I have a square area with a background hexagonal tiling. When I click on a certain point of the area I want the hexagon placed there to show/hide.

[image]

I've implemented it as follows:

1. Calculate hexagon-center points (`vert1`, `vert2`, `centerPoints`)
2. Calculate vertices of each hexagon (`vertices`)
3. Create hexagons using the vertices (`polygons`)
4. ClickPane&Graphics. On click:
   i.$\ $ Check in what polygon is the clicked point (using `Element`)
   ii. Add or remove it from a list with visible hexagons (`activeHexagons`)

```
Manipulate[
 (*Center Points*)
 vert1 = Table[
   r*{3 x, Sqrt[3] y}, {x, 0, Ceiling[a/(3 r)]}, {y, 0, 
    Ceiling[b/(Sqrt[3]*r)]}];
 vert2 = Map[# + {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}*r &, vert1, {2}];
 centerPoints = Flatten[Join[vert1, vert2], 1];
 vertices = 
  ConstantArray[#, 7] + 
     r*Table[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 
        2 π, π/3}] & /@ centerPoints;
 polygons = Polygon /@ vertices[[All, 1 ;; 6]];
 DynamicModule[{activeHexagons = {},
   clickedHexagon,
   pt},
  ClickPane[Framed @ Show[
     Graphics[Dynamic@(Line /@ vertices[[activeHexagons]]), 
      PlotRange -> {{0, a}, {0, b}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic],
     Graphics[Dynamic@(Point /@ centerPoints[[activeHexagons]])]
     ],
   (pt = #;
     clickedHexagon = 
      Flatten[Position[Element[pt, #] & /@ polygons, True]][[1]];
     activeHexagons = If[
       MemberQ[activeHexagons, clickedHexagon],
       DeleteCases[activeHexagons, clickedHexagon],
       AppendTo[activeHexagons, clickedHexagon]]) &]],
 {{a, 7, "Honeycomb width"}, 2, 8},
 {{b, 7, "Honeycomb height"}, 2, 8},
 {{r, 0.2, "Hexagon radius"}, 0.1, 3}]
```

For areas with many hexagons my code is really slow (with default manipulate parameters >2s delay between mouse-click and displaying the hexagon). **How can I make it faster?**

(For now resizing the area/hexagon size with `Manipulate` changes the relative position of the hexagons. Keeping the relative position would be nicer but isn't really important)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottleneck here is the part clickedHexagon = 
      Flatten[Position[Element[pt, #] & /@ polygons, True]].  You could use Nearest function for this.

```
Manipulate[(*Center Points*)
 centerPoints = 
  Flatten[Table[{#, # + {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}*r} &[r*{3 x, Sqrt[3] y}], {x,
      0, Ceiling[a/(3 r)]}, {y, 0, Ceiling[b/(Sqrt[3]*r)]}], 2];
 nearPoint = Nearest[centerPoints];
 DynamicModule[{activeHexagons = {}, clickedHexagon, pt},
  Row@{DynamicWrapper[Spacer[0], 
     activeHexagons = 
      DeleteDuplicates[(nearPoint /@ activeHexagons)[[All, 1]]]], 
    ClickPane[
     Framed@
      Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], 
         Dynamic@{RegularPolygon[#, r, 6] & /@ activeHexagons, 
           Point[activeHexagons]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, a}, {0, b}}, 
        AspectRatio -> Automatic], ImageSize -> 300], (pt = #;
       clickedHexagon = First[nearPoint[pt]];
       activeHexagons = 
        If[MemberQ[activeHexagons, clickedHexagon], 
         DeleteCases[activeHexagons, clickedHexagon], 
         AppendTo[activeHexagons, clickedHexagon]
         ]) &]}], {{a, 7, "Honeycomb width"}, 2, 
  8}, {{b, 7, "Honeycomb height"}, 2, 8}, {{r, 0.2, "Hexagon radius"},
   0.1, 3}]
```